# I keep getting this error "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer"

Tags: c#

I've recently been getting into c# programming and now have started doing a few exercises of it. One of the exercises goes as following : "If we list all the natural numbers below 10 that are multiples of 3 or 5, we get 3, 5, 6 and 9. Find the sum of all the multiples."
I totally do not understand why this can't work. When debugging this error appears " The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer "  for the 2 bool lines and the if statement line

```
{
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {
      bool y = x%3=0;
      bool z = x%5=0;
      if (y = true || z = true) {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        break;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if(y == true || z == true)`  Since you are evaluating, two equal signs.  Since they are bools, you can simplify it to just `if (y || z)`

Comment: @LarsTech: Though you are right that this code is *wrong*, it's not the wrong code that is producing the error.

Comment: By the way, the `break;` statement isn't needed since you don't need to break out of the `for()` loop. You can factor out `break;`, refactor the `if()` and also eliminate the `{}` under the `if()`. The refactoring could like like this:  `if (y || z) Console.WriteLine(x);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In C#, `=` means assignment to a variable or property. `==` means comparison.

This:

```
       bool y = x % 3 = 0;
       bool z = x % 5 = 0;
```

means "assign 0 to `x % 3` (and to `y`, though that is considered poor style in C#)", but `x % 3`  is not something you can assign to. You meant

```
       bool y = x % 3 == 0;
       bool z = x % 5 == 0;
```

Now, while we're at it, let's get you into good habits while you're a new C# programmer so that you don't have to be broken of them later.

Plainly you are making an attempt at fizzbuzz-style questions, which means that you are probably practicing for an interview.  Interviewers will look for small details.

```
  bool y = x % 3 == 0;
  bool z = x % 5 == 0;
```

Why `x`, `y` and `z`?  What do those mean?  Nothing.  You had a choice of **any text in the universe** and you chose to pick text that was meaningless.  Interviewers notice that.

```
  bool divisbleByThree = current % 3 == 0;
  bool divisibleByFive = current % 5 == 0;
```

Moving on:

```
if (y == true || z == true) {
```

Nothing says "I'm a novice programmer" louder than making a Boolean that compares a Boolean to a Boolean.  `y` and `z` are *already* either true or false; comparing them to `true` is an *identity operation*. It's completely unnecessary because the answer to "is it true that it is true?" is the same as the answer to "is it true?"  Just write

```
if (divisibleByThree || divisibleByFive)
{
```

Also note that most C# programmers do not use "disco style" bracing.  Burn the extra line and put the brace down a line.

Comment: Nothing bothers me more than the disco style bracing.. it's so ugly and makes it hard to read sometimes.

Comment: Dang - I am not keeping up. Disco?

Comment: @Clay: Here, let John Travolta show you where the braces go when he programs. https://www.martelnyc.com/body-decorations/images/8715_641_388-john-travolta-dance-scene.jpg

Comment: Plenty of people use "disco" style... most place I've worked do and I prefer it myself.  Don't confuse your preferences for best practices.  Otherwise 10/10 answer.

Comment: @WilliamPrevett: If I had my druthers, bracing style would be enforced by the compiler and then there wouldn't be any arguments ever again. Sadly that was just one of the many improvements to C# that I never got in. :)

Comment: Some alternate timeline is closing hundreds of daily "Why does my code cause CSXXXX: Unexpected Brace?" questions as duplicates.

Comment: @JonathonChase: Hah, that's a good point. Probably what I'd do is make it a warning, not an error, and it could be automatically fixed by common editors when they save. I am just this month starting to learn about Python; I'd be interested to know if there are a lot of Python questions about indentation style being enforced.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was very helpful :D

Comment: @WilliamPrevett: That's a bit unfair.  It's a preference because Eric Lippert likes it.  It's a good practice because Visual Studio likes it and because  [Microsoft Likes It](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/inside-a-program/coding-conventions) .  If you're new to programming, copying the coding conventions of either your toolset (recommended as a starting point) and from the language designers (recommended when the toolset offers no preference) is a good way to keep your code using the same style as other developers.

Comment: @EricLippert: Enforced indentation doesn't cause big problems in Python until you mix tabs and spaces, resulting in identical-looking code being rejected by the compiler.  Personally, I consider this more of a tooling problem than a developer training problem.

Comment: @Brian: Indeed, again, if I had my druthers there would be no controversy because formatting characters like tabstops and other non-printing character codes would be lexical errors. These features cause more costs than benefits. And its not like there is a product whose success in the marketplace can be attributed to using tabs vs spaces, or the one true bracing style.

Comment: @Brian Visual studio can be configured however you want.  The best practice would be to be consistent in whatever style you choose.  I'm not saying one way is inherently better than the other.  I'm just saying let's not impose our preferences on others as if there's some true way of doing things.  Except dark themes of course.  (kidding)

Comment: @Silver.Chariot.2: If your problem has been solved please mark one of the answers as accepted so that people know to stop looking at the question.

Answer (score 0):

You're using an incorrect operator.

```
   // = Operator means: x IS EQUAL to y.
   // == Operator means: IS x EQUAL to y?

    if(y == true || z == true) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        break;
    }
```

Also you can simplify your if conditional by just using this

```
//Your variables are of a bool datatype so they're only going to return True or False.
    if( y || Z)
```

Answer (score -1):

The issue as people have pointed out is this line:

```
x % 3 = 0;
```

Your trying do a comparison equation, but are instead assigning 0 to 3.
You need to do

x % 3 == 0

Often I find it helpful to use braces, even though it is simple.

I'm not sure if you've gotten confused, but you can do something like:

```
3 % x = 0
```

In the above case it actually assigns x to zero and modules 3 by x (which has become 0)